# console.log() messages don't show up from Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating my first Firefox extension using the Addon SDK, but I can't get messages I pass with console.log() to appear in my debugger.

I created a new profile in Firefox 33 and installed the latest version of Firebug. When I launch my addon using `cfx run -p <My_Profile_Directory>` I can see both Firebug and my addon, and the addon does what it's supposed to do. However, I don't see anywhere messages I wrote to log using the `console.log()` command

Here's my **main.js** so far:

```
function loginToSite(user, password) {
    var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;

    var doLogin = Request(
        {
            url: "https://website.com/login/index.php",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            content: "username=xxxx&password=xxxx&remember=1",
            onComplete: function(response) {
                console.log(response.text);
            }
        }
    );

    doLogin.post();
}

function checkLoginStatus(tab) {
    //TODO Actually check if the tab is logged in, currently assume it's not
    loginToSite(0,0);
}

// Listens for tabs and checks each loaded tab if it's the website
tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {
    var tabUrl = tab.url.toLowerCase();
    if(tabUrl.contains("website.com")) {
        console.log("Not connected to website.com, running login procedure");
        checkLoginStatus(tab);
    }
});
```

Like I said, I'm actually being logged in automatically, but no log messages appear in either Firebug's or the Firefox Developer Tools' console.

What am I doing wrong here? Where are the log messages?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the default logging level (`error`) to something more verbose, like `info`.

The global level is controlled by the preference `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel`. But you can adjust the logging level of your extension only, with the preference `extensions.myExtensionID.sdk.console.logLevel`

When you run `cfx` without passing a profile directory, it takes care of setting up the temporary profile to be developer friendly.